# Find recurrence relation??

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I am trying to understand the following problem:

> For each integer $n \geq 1$,let $t_n$ be the number of strings of $n$ letters that can be produced by concatenating copies of the string 'a','bb' and 'cc'.
>
> For example:
>
> $t_1=1$ ('a' is the only possible string)
>
> $t_2=3$ ('aa','bb' and 'cc').
>
> a) Find $t_3$ and $t_4$.

My guess: Is $t_3=0$ and $t_4=0$?

> b) Find a recurrence for $t_n$ that holds for all $n \geq 3$. Explain why your recurrence gives $t_n$.

I do not see how to find the recurrence.

Comment: Have you seen the recurrence relation for tiling an $n\times 1$ grid with squares and dominos?  The proof and result will be almost identical, except in this case we have squares (*a's*) red dominos (*bb's*) and blue dominos (*cc's*).

Comment: Also, it should be pointed out, the set of strings $T_2 = \{$`aa`,`bb`,`cc`$\}$ with `aa` a length $2$ string, not `a` a length $1$ string.  If you haven't seen the recurrence I describe from the first comment, the important observation to make here is that any string will end with exactly one of `a`,`b`, or `c`, and if it does end with `b` or `c` the character right before it must also be the same.  What precedes it can by anything however.

Comment: So t3=3 & t4=3?

Comment: And where is the example for the dominos?

Comment: How many allowable strings of length $n$ start with $a$? with $b$? with $c$?

Comment: "Where is the example with the dominoes?" In practically every textbook that has more than one sentence mentioning recurrence relations.  It is the quintessential  example.  And no, t3 and t4 are definitely not equal to 3

Comment: Your guesses are very wrong.  If you tell us what you do and don't understand, we can help you better.  Do you know what concatenation is?  Do you understand why $t_2$ is 3?  Do you understand that $t_3$ is the number of 3 letter strings, like 'aaa', 'abb', and so on?

Answer (score 1):

a) consider possible string of length $3$.

Notice that $a$ must be used as it is the only small building block of odd length. It can be used $1$ time, or $3$ times.

$$abb, acc, bba, cca, aaa$$

Now consider possible string of length $4$.

Cases where $a$ is used $4$ times: $$aaaa$$

Cases where $a$ is used twice: $$aabb, abba, bbaa$$

$$aacc, acca, ccaa$$

Cases where $a$ is not used.

$$bbbb, cccc, bbcc, ccbb$$

b) Hint for part b.

Consider what if the string of length $n$ begins with $a$. Then we just have to concatenate $a$ with another string of length $n-1$.

What about string of length $n$ that begins with $b$ and $c$?

Comment: But I can't even find a recurrence relation for when the string of length n begins with a?

Comment: Do you agree that number of $3$ letters string that begins with $a$ is equal to the number of $2$ letter string?

Comment: it is like $XYZ$. if I know $X=a$, I just have to figure out what is $YZ$.

Comment: Ya  and the number of 4 letters strings that begin with b and c is equal to the the 2 letter string.But I still can't write a recurrence relation?

Comment: Is the recurrence relation tn=t(n-1) + 2t(n-2)?

Comment: congratulations.