# Recurence Relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics

For each integer $n \geq 1$, let tn be the number of strings of $n$ letters that can be produced by concatenating (running together) copies of the strings $“a”, “bb”, and “cc”$.

For example, $t_{1} = 1$ ($“a”$ is the only possible string) and $t_{2} = 3$ ($“aa”, “bb” and “cc”$ are the possible strings).

(a) Find $t_{3}$and $t_{4}$.

My answer for $t_{3}$ is $aaa,bbb,ccc,abb,acc,bba,cca$.

My answer for $t_{4}$ is $aaaa,bbbb,cccc,abba,acca,bbaa,ccaa,bbcc,ccbb$.

Is this right ?

Comment: 'bb' isn't valid for $t_3$.

Answer (score 0):

consider possible string of length $3$.

Notice that $a$ must be used as it is the only small building block of odd length. It can be used $1$ time, or $3$ times.

$$abb, acc, bba, cca, aaa$$

Now consider possible string of length $4$.

Cases where $a$ is used $4$ times: $$aaaa$$

Cases where $a$ is used twice: $$aabb, abba, bbaa$$

$$aacc, acca, ccaa$$

Cases where $a$ is not used.

$$bbbb, cccc, bbcc, ccbb$$

Comment: so for t4 there are 11 possibilities right bro

Comment: seems to be so.

Comment: hey bro just one more,if i had to find the recurrence for tn that holds for all n ≥ 3 what would it be . quite diffuclt this part

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2292900/find-recurrence-relation/2293952#2293952  I just found this and I answered the second part with a hint.